# Sample asp.net MVC: modal popup with list of customers. After select return custID to parent

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, modal-dialog

how do I create a modal popup which shows a MVC-view with customers in which I can select a certain customer and the customer ID is returned to the model after selection?

Has somebody a simple skeleton to show as an example?

Best regards, Janno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the bootstrap framework modal component. Fill the modal with a partial view, then use the javascript events to return the selection back to your main form.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals